# how to use Python requests to post a binary stream with parameters?

Tags: python

there is my code:
client:

```
def upload(url,file):
    file_name=file.split('\\')[-1]

    with open(file,'rb') as f:
        r=requests.post(url,data=f)
```

server side:

```
    $datastr = fopen('php://input',"rb");
    $filename='upload/111.bin';
    if ($fp = fopen($filename,"wb")){
    while(!feof($datastr)){
        fwrite($fp,fread($datastr,4096)) ;
        }
    }
```

it can work, but I don't know how to post the file stream with file name.
if I use `r=requests.post(url,data={ 'name':file_name, 'file':open(file,'rb') })`, $_POST is null

Comment: if only post file stream, it can works ```with open(file,'rb') as f:
        r=requests.post(url,data=f)```  but I don't know how to post the stream with file name.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) you can POST a multipart file with requests, but to POST it as a stream you should use [requests-toolbelt](https://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/uploading-data.html#streaming-multipart-data-encoder).

If no streaming is actually required, you could modify your code to be:

```
def upload(url,file):
    file_name=file.split('\\')[-1]

with open(file,'rb') as f:
    r=requests.post(url,files={"file": (file_name, f)})
```

Using `files` in this way let’s you include file name and other header info (see docs for more information)

Comment: I need to POST a stream, but I also need to know the name of stream file. So I'm confused with that.

Comment: Okay. See the requests toolbar link I included. You should build a multipart encoder and possibly wrap it in a monitor too. If that’s what you’re looking for I’ll edit my answer to include that

Comment: I have tried MultipartEncoder, if only post file stream it can work. but if I want to post file name and stream together, $_POST is null. Here is my code.
```def upload_multipart(url,file_path):
    file_name=file_path.split('\\')[-1]
    encoder=MultipartEncoder(
        fields={
            'filename':file_name,
            'file':(file_name,open(file_path,'rb'),'application/octet-stream')})
    data=MultipartEncoderMonitor(encoder,upload_callback)
    response=requests.post(url,data=data,headers={'Content-Type':data.content_type})```